# Liberar espacio utilizado en BBDD Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en VB.net (4.5) usando como BBDD Access (2016), pero tengo un pequeño problema: cuando inserto un registro (por ejemplo un Richtextbox convertido en Byte()) el tamaño de la BBDD aumenta. Pero cuando lo elimino, el tamaño no disminuye (se queda como estaba). Por tanto, conforme voy insertando y eliminando registros la BBDD no deja de crecer en MB.

He podido comprobar que cuando reinicio el PC, la BBDD sí que "libera" espacio.
¿A qué puede deberse?

PD: Estoy haciendo los `.close()` y `.dispose()` necesarios en mi clase de acceso a BBDD.

Comment: _pista_: lo que quieres hacer se llama compactar.

Comment: ¿Es posible que agregues la rutina que usas para eliminar? (la parte importante)

Answer (score 1):

El problema que veo con esto de la compactación es cuándo realizarlo.
La aplicación va a permitir crear nuevas BBDD al gusto del usuario, y puede ubicarlas donde le dé la gana. Por tanto:

- No sé qué BBDD hay, ya que no es fija.
- Además, las BBDD pueden ser usadas por varios usuarios, así que si me pongo a compactar mientras hay usuarios dentro...
- ¿Cuándo compactar? ¿Siempre que se haga un DELETE?

Comment: solo con el hecho de que la db es compartida con varios usuario deberias evaluar cambiar de base de datos, por ejemplo Sql Server, al compartirse la db en red no aplica una db Ms Access

Comment: Soy totalmente consciente de las limitaciones de Access, pero es una imposición que me han hecho: querían una DB que fuera un fichero físico, para poder usarlo es un servidor de fichero, no usarlo como "servicio".

Comment: No se quien habra puesto la imposicion pero deberia conocer algo mas sobre las base de datos, esta claro que quien tomo esa decision no conoce mucho sobre el tema. Particularmente le recomendaria que reevalue y analice cambiar de base de datos, usar la db como archivo esta pensado para un uso local, no remoto y compartido a multimpels usuarios, para eso se creo la db como servicio

Comment: Estoy totalmente de acuerdo contigo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que Ms Access no libera el espacio por eso debes compactar

[Cómo compactar una base de datos Access con JRO](http://www.mvp-access.es/softjaen/bases/adonet/sjadonet21.htm)

Como observaras se usa una libreria distinta a `ADO.NET`, por lo que tendras que agregar la referencia a `Microsoft Jet and Replication Object 2.6 Library`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código es bastante simple, ya que solo implica invocar el metodo `CompactDatabase()`, pero hay que indicar dos connection string, porque al compactar generar el volcado a una nueva db que luego podras renombrar

```
Dim jro As JRO.JetEngine = New JRO.JetEngine()

' Compactamos la base de datos
'
jro.CompactDatabase(connStringOrigen, connStringDestino)

Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(jro)
```

El `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` es importante para liberar correctamente los recursos de una instancia COM